# How can I get some value from my Firebase?

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to solve how to get a value from my DatabaseReference, but doing so gives me the full address when I want to put it in a TextView

This is the reference:

```
  public static DatabaseReference getUsernameRef(String email){
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("nom_usuarios");
```

These are the values that I want to rescue:

[image: values to rescue photo]

i tried this:

```
 mPosti.setUsername(FirebaseUtils.getUsernameRef(FirebaseUtils.getCurrentUser().getEmail()).toString());
```

But instead of receiving the value, I get the address of the database.

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events

Answer (score 0):

```
         DatabaseReference database =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("nom_usuaios").getRef();
         database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // here you will the value in datasnapshot
               for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    list.add(dataSnapshot.getValue());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: there are two more listener in firebase to retrieve the value, please refer documentation.